# calculating consecutive 1's in a Binary number

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
class Solve
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i=0,count=0;
    int[] arr = new int[10];
    int n =in.nextInt();
    while(n!=0)
    {
      arr[i]=n%2;
      i++;
      n=n/2;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
  }

  }
}
```

I just want to calculate number of consecutive 1's. ? like 1110011001 will give me answer  5.. How can i do that??

Comment: Why did you post this code? Does it try to achieve the goal you've mentioned? Does it fail? Why does it fail?

Comment: 1110011001 doesn't have 5 consecutive 1's.

Comment: the code is just converting a decimal number to Binary number.. i' m supposed to work after that @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: @shmosel I suppose `5` is calculated from the initial three consecutive `1`s *plus* the middle two `1`s. Therefore it's not the longest streak of consecutive numbers, but rather the amount of `1`s that appear next to another `1`

Comment: 111 and 11 aren't they consecutive?? @shmosel

Comment: @shmosel Yes, so that's `5` digits in total

Comment: @nimittchauhan Consecutive - "following one after the other in order". 111 and 11 are not consecutive because they're not following one after the other - there is 00 in between. The longest consecutive number of 1's in your string is 3 - and there are three groups of consecutive 1's that are not consecutive to each other. They have lengths 3, 2 and 1.

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n).replaceAll("(0|(?<!1)1(?!1))", "").length());
```

The regex means: *replace all 0's and any 1 not preceded or followed by another 1*

Comment: Check the regex, it's printing 8 instead of 5.

Comment: @Nooblhu no it's not.

Comment: @Nooblhu looks like you're testing with with `n = 1110011001`. But `1110011001` is supposed to be binary; that is, `n = 921`.

Comment: So whats your test case?

Comment: @Nooblhu `"1110011001".replaceAll("(0|(?<!1)1(?!1))", "").length()`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this as a String [Edited to sum all consecutive 1's]:

```
String binary = in.nextLine();
String[] arrayBin = binary.split("0+"); // an array of strings without 0's

int result=0;

for (int i=0; i < arrayBin.length; i++){
if (arrayBin[i].length()<2){
result+=0;
}
else {
result+=arrayBin[i].length();
}
}
System.out.println("Total consecutive = "+result);
```

Comment: OP wants 5, not 3.

Comment: With Java 8 you can do `Arrays.stream(binary.split("0+")).mapToInt(String::length).filter(l -> l > 1).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

We can identify two consecutive binary ones in the least significant positions like this:

```
(value & 0b11) == 0b11
```

We can move the bits in value to the right like so:

```
value >>>= 1;
```

It's important to use tripple `>>>` over double `>>` because we don't care about the sign bit.

Then all we have to do is keep track of the number of consecutive `1`s:

```
int count(int value) {
    int count = 1;
    int total = 0;
    while (value != 0) {
        if ((value & 0b11) == 0b11) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count > 1) {
                total += count;
            }
            count = 1;
        }
        value >>>= 1;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Test cases:

```
assertEquals(0, count(0b0));
assertEquals(0, count(0b1));
assertEquals(0, count(0b10));
assertEquals(2, count(0b11));
assertEquals(5, count(0b1110011));
assertEquals(5, count(0b1100111));
assertEquals(6, count(0b1110111));
assertEquals(7, count(0b1111111));
assertEquals(32, count(-1));
```

If you only want the length of the maximum, I have a similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42609478/360211

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Brian Kernighan’s Algorithm for counting the highest consecutive number of 1's.
A java pseudocode would be something like this

```
    // Initialize result
    int count = 0;

    // Count the number of iterations to
    // reach n = 0.
    while (n!=0)
    {
        // This operation reduces length
        // of every sequence of 1s by one.
        n = (n & (n << 1));
        count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Solution {
public int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(int[] nums) {
    if(nums == null || nums.length == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    int counter = 0, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i] == 1){
            counter += nums[i];
        } else{
            counter = nums[i];
        }
        max = Math.max(counter, max);
    }
    return max;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To this problem one trick which we can use here with help of some Java operators.
    & operator and left shift (<<) in java.

Code snippet will be like :

```
public getConsecutiveCount(int inputNumber)
{
  int count = 0 ;
  while(inputNumber != 0)
  {
     inputNumber = inputNumber & (inputNumber << 1);
   count++;
  }
}
```

Explanation :

This function is taking input (ex : we want to check how many
     consecutive 1's integer 6 have in its binary representation)

so out input number will be like :

```
 inputNumber = ((110) & ((110)<<1))    {This left shift will result in 100  so final op :
                                        110 & 100 which 100 , every time '0' is added to 
                                        our result and we iterate until whole number will 
                                        be zero and value of our count variable will be 
                                        our expected outcome }
```

Answer (score 0):

To find Maximum consecutive 1's in binary(like 101)

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string[] base2=Convert.ToString(n,2).Split('0');

int count=0;

foreach(string s in base2)
    count=s.Length>count?s.Length:count;


Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    String bs = Integer.toBinaryString(n);// bs=Binary String
    char[] characters = bs.toCharArray();
    int max = 1;
    int temp = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length - 1; i++) {
        if (characters[i] == characters[i + 1] & characters[i] == '1' & characters[i + 1] == '1') {
            temp++;
            if (temp > max) {
                max = temp;
            }
        } else {
            temp = 1;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

/* Given a decimal number print maximum number of consecutive 1's after binary conversion */

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public void countBinaryOne(int num){
        int var =0, countOne= 0, maxCt=0;
        while(num>0){
            var= num%2;    
                if(var==1){
                    countOne=countOne+1;
                }else{
                    if(maxCt<countOne){    
                        maxCt= countOne;    
                        countOne=0;
                    }else{
                        countOne=0;
                }
            }

            num=num/2;          
        }
        System.out.println(Math.max(countOne,maxCt));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n= in.nextInt();
        Solution sol= new Solution();
        sol.countBinaryOne(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void digitBinaryCountIfOne(int n){

    int reminder=0, sum=0, total = 0;

    while(n>0)
        {
        reminder = n%2;
        n/=2;
            if(reminder==1){
            sum++;
                if(sum>=total)
                    total=sum;


            }else{
                sum=0;
                }   

        } 
        System.out.println(total);
}
```