# Count maximum consecutives 1's in binary number

Tags: java

How can I count in Java the maximum consecutive 1's from a binary number?
For instance, the user enters an integer like 13 this would be in binary 1101.
The binary number 1101 has 2 consecutive one's, so the output should be 2.
Another example the number 5 would be in binary 0101, so the output should be 1. My program doesn't work correctly if I type the number 439.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numb = scanner.nextInt();
        int tempCount = 0;
        int count = 0; 

        // numb = 439 -> output 3
        // numb = 13  -> output 2
        // numb = 1   -> output 1 
        while (numb >= 1) {

            if (numb % 2 != 0) {

                tempCount++;
                numb /= 2;
                count = tempCount;
                if (numb % 2 != 0) {
                    tempCount++;
                    count = tempCount;
                    numb /= 2;
                }

            }
            else {
                numb /= 2;
                tempCount = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Do you have to implement your own decimal->binary method ? if not you can use Integer.toBinaryString()

Comment: No, I just I have to take an int number and output how many consecutive ones are there in the binary version of the number.

Comment: What should result of `1110111` be? 3 or 6?

Comment: For the binary number 1110111 the result should be 3

Comment: Reopened in that case, not the same as other question.

Comment: You're supposed to find the longest sequence. What is count? What is tempCount? There should be something in the code changing the result with the current sequence length if the current length is bigger than the max length found. But I don't see that in the code. Choose good variable names, it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you intended `count` to be the length of the longest sequence of 1s, while `tempCount` is the number of 1s in the sequence your currently counting. So you should only assign `tempCount` to `count` if it is greater than `count`. For 439, I believe you are correctly counting three 1s. Then comes a 0, and you correctly reset `tempCount` to zero. Next time you count a 1, you correctly increment `tempCount` to one, then assign this one to `count` too, and your count of three gets lost.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, here is the solution.
I have forgotten an nested if statement.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int numb = scanner.nextInt();
int tempCount = 0; //save temporarily the longest sequence of one's in this variable 
int count = 0; // before the sequence of one's gets interrupted, I save the value from tempCount in count

// numb = 439 -> output 3
// numb = 13  -> output 2
// numb = 1   -> output 1 
while (numb >= 1) {

    if (numb % 2 != 0) {

        tempCount++;
        numb /= 2;
        if(count < tempCount){
            count = tempCount;
        }

    }
    else {
        numb /= 2;
        tempCount = 0;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can identify two consecutive binary ones in the least significant positions like this:

```
(value & 0b11) == 0b11
```

We can move the bits in value to the right like so:

```
value >>>= 1;
```

It's important to use tripple `>>>` over double `>>` because we don't care about the sign bit.

Then all we have to do is keep track of the maximum number of consecutive `1`s:

```
int countMax1Streak(int value) { // value could also be a long if required
    int max = 0;
    int count = 1;
    while (value != 0) {
        if ((value & 0b11) == 0b11) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 1;
        }
        value >>>= 1;
        if (count > max) {
            max = count;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Test cases:

```
assertEquals(0, countMax1Streak(0b0));
assertEquals(1, countMax1Streak(0b1));
assertEquals(1, countMax1Streak(0b10));
assertEquals(2, countMax1Streak(0b11));
assertEquals(3, countMax1Streak(0b1110011));
assertEquals(3, countMax1Streak(0b1100111));
assertEquals(3, countMax1Streak(0b1110111));
assertEquals(7, countMax1Streak(0b1111111));
assertEquals(32, countMax1Streak(-1));
```

You can also use to count the maximum 0 streak like so:

```
public int countMax0Streak(int value) {
    return countMax1Streak(~value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. Here is a solution that is generic and also considers all the `long` values possible (your solution may not work for negative number if you check for the value of `n`) in Java:

```
public class LongestBitStreak {

/**
 * Returns the longest <i>streak</i> of the given bit b in 
   given number n. 
 * A bit streak is defined as a consecutive sequence of the given bit. 
 * @param n the number to find streak in
 * @param b the bit whose streak is to be found
 * @return the <i>longest</i> bit streak
 */
static int get(long n, int b) {
    if (b != 0 && b != 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("second arg: (" + b + ") must be 0 or 1");
    int streak = 0, maxStreak = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        if ((n & 1) == b) {
            streak += 1;
            maxStreak = Math.max(streak, maxStreak);
        } else {
            streak = 0;
        }
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return maxStreak;
}
```

}

Here's an interesting unit test:

```
@Test
public void foolProof() {
    long n = 0b11111000001111100110101010;
    long nc = ~n; // One's complement of n
    System.out.println(get(n, 1));
    System.out.println(get(nc, 0));
    assertEquals(get(n, 1), get(nc, 0));
    assertEquals(get(n, 0), get(nc, 1));
}
```

Note that some optimizations are possible based on the values of number and bit, but this should be a decent solution for starters.

Comment: Your test case shows that to count the opposite type of bit, all you have to do is not `~` the input, so the parameter `b` is overkill. It's very close to my answer, but notice how I don't need to know the number of bits in the input.